# Mistake on application regarding length of stay

Tags: united-kingdom

I recently submitted a tier 2/work shortage application. On the application, I put I would be in the U.K. for seven years, because that is my hope. Unfortunately, my COS is for three with the ability to renew. I then went on and paid for three years of healthcare, but paid for a five year visa. I didn’t realize my mistake until after it was submitted and my biometric was completed. I paid for the 3-5 day expedited visa. This is day six and I’ve heard nothing. What are the chances this will work out? I’m in a panic.

Comment: What does COS stand for?  (Probably best to just [edit] the question to replace the abbreviation with the words in full.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Certificate of sponsorship

Comment: It is hard to answer a "what are the chances" question. I would guess you have a high chance of being rejected due to the mismatch between the CoS length and the visa you've applied for. But at this point there's nothing you can do but wait, so don't stress about it too much. You can always reapply.